# Получаю ошибку "The result of `subscribe` is not used", после обновления до Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, rxjava

Сегодня обновился до Android Studio 3.1, теперь не могу толком использовать RX Java.

[image: Прикладываю картинку, того как выглядит мой код, также убрал лямды, чтобы было наглядее видно]

РАньше такого не было.

---

```
public interface IApiRequest {

    @POST("/v1/register")
    Observable<Response> makeRegister(@Query("email") String email,
                                      @Query("password") String password);
}



public class ApiRequest {

private static IApiRequest init(){
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://*****")
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build().create(IApiRequest.class);
}

public static Observable<Response> makeRegister(String email, String password){
    return init().makeRegister(email, password);
}
```

}

Код 100% рабочий, так как я всегда так и раньше писал, проверил на старых проектах.

Также попытался обновить RX через gradle, все равно, тоже самое.

Читал вот тут похожее https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522619/the-result-of-subscribe-is-not-used.

***Но ответа там так и не дали однозначного, как вернуть все как было раньше?***

Answer (score 1):

Это просто предупреждение о возможной ошибке, которая заключается в том, что метод `subscribe` возвращает какое-то значение, но вы его не используете.

Та же ситуация у вас произойдёт с любым другим подобным случаем. Например при создании папок методом `File#mkdirs()`, возвращающим `true/false` в зависимости от того создались ли папки или они уже есть.

Вы можете избавиться от этого предупреждения 2 способами:

1. Выставить в настройках студии запрет на эту проверку.
2. Использовать возвращаемое значение метода.

Первый вариант не рекомендуется - так вы можете пропустить к-л проблемное место.

Второй вариант - поместить полученный `Subscription` в `CompositeSubscription`, который можно очищать при завершении презентера в методе `onDestroy`

Comment: А почему в версиии Android Studio 3.0, такой ошибки не было?. Я заметил кстати что там раньше использовался другой класс вместо Consumer.

Comment: А может нужно просто код переделать? чтобы такого сообщения не было?. Не пойму, почему раньше работало нормально